How to get Strapi V5 hosted in App service to connect to Postgresql
I have done the following steps:

Deployed a Web App + Database in Azure (Postgresql) - This configures a vnet so db can be accessed privately from the web app service.

I have setup a storage account and container

I have changed the environment variables to the app service to match those in the strapi config for the database and the storage container:
 [{
 "name": "ADMIN_JWT_SECRET",
 "value": "Blahldsflsf",
 "slotSetting": false},{
 "name": "API_TOKEN_SALT",
 "value": "asdfasdfasdf",
 "slotSetting": false},{
 "name": "APP_KEYS",
 "value": "asdfdsafsadfsadfsadf",
 "slotSetting": false},{
 "name": "AZURE_REDIS_CONNECTIONSTRING",
 "value": "rediss://:asdfsafsdfsdf=@myapp-strapi-cache.redis.cache.windows.net:6380/0",
 "slotSetting": true},{
 "name": "DATABASE_CLIENT",
 "value": "postgres",
 "slotSetting": false},{
 "name": "DATABASE_HOST",
 "value": "myapp-server.postgres.database.azure.com",
 "slotSetting": false},{
 "name": "DATABASE_NAME",
 "value": "myapp-strapi-database",
 "slotSetting": false},{
 "name": "DATABASE_PASSWORD",
 "value": "dsafdfsafsdaf",
 "slotSetting": false},{
 "name": "DATABASE_PORT",
 "value": "5432",
 "slotSetting": false},{
 "name": "DATABASE_SSL",
 "value": "true",
 "slotSetting": false},{
 "name": "DATABASE_USERNAME",
 "value": "myappuser",
 "slotSetting": false},{
 "name": "HOST",
 "value": "0.0.0.0",
 "slotSetting": false},{
 "name": "JWT_SECRET",
 "value": "asdfasdfasf",
 "slotSetting": false},{
 "name": "PORT",
 "value": "8080",
 "slotSetting": false},{
 "name": "STORAGE_ACCOUNT",
 "value": "myappapistorage",
 "slotSetting": false},{
 "name": "STORAGE_ACCOUNT_CONTAINER",
 "value": "myapp-container",
 "slotSetting": false},{
 "name": "STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY",
 "value": "dsafdsafdsafdsa",
 "slotSetting": false},{
 "name": "STORAGE_URL",
 "value": "https://myappapistorage.blob.core.windows.net/",
 "slotSetting": false},{
 "name": "TRANSFER_TOKEN_SALT",
 "value": "adsfasdfasdfasdfsadfasf",
 "slotSetting": false}]


I have added the storage container info to plugin.ts in strapi code:
 export default ({env}) => ({
 upload: !process.env.NODE_ENV || process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? {} : {
     config: {
       provider: "strapi-provider-upload-azure-storage",
       providerOptions: {
         serviceBaseURL: env("STORAGE_URL"), // optional
         account: env("STORAGE_ACCOUNT"),
         accountKey: env("STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY"),//either account key or sas token is enough to make authentication 
         containerName: env("STORAGE_CONTAINER_NAME"),
         defaultPath: "assets",
       },
     },
 }});



5.I have deployed via github actions and deployment successful but had to add to startup config to get admin page to come up (this was suggested in another question on SO and it in facts works to get the app to start up correctly):
pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot/dist/build --no-daemon --spa

The website deploys as indicated and I can access the admin panel but I cannot register the first admin user. Its as though the app cannot see the database for some reason to do the next action and is erroring out behind the scenes. I SSH into the web app and I can do nslookup and see the database in the vnet subnet and the ip address so it does look like azures web app + database did setup the connection and networking right so I think its on the app side and not really an azure issue. I did create a test postgresql database in azure and made public facing and connected from my home local environment and it worked surprisingly. I check log strream but that never seems to give any good info related to errors during runtime. So I am curious how do I debug this and what could possibly cause this?
Log stream:
    Connected!
2024-09-13T21:55:41  Welcome, you are now connected to log-streaming service.Starting Log Tail -n 10 of existing logs ----/home/LogFiles/__lastCheckTime.txt  (https://mosaic-strapi-c3e3g3ebavbmfyas.scm.eastus2-01.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/__lastCheckTime.txt)09/13/2024 19:30:25/home/LogFiles/kudu/trace/090552f3fb88-409c778c-15e8-42c9-b2a1-6b4e955dc953.txt  (https://mosaic-strapi-c3e3g3ebavbmfyas.scm.eastus2-01.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace/090552f3fb88-409c778c-15e8-42c9-b2a1-6b4e955dc953.txt)
2024-09-13T21:00:56  Startup Request, url: /api/deployments/?api-version=2022-03-01, method: GET, type: request, pid: 87,1,5, ScmType: GitHubAction/home/LogFiles/kudu/trace/09363ba12457-e199d32e-04ce-4375-8fa5-2b14bce9f4e6.txt  (https://mosaic-strapi-c3e3g3ebavbmfyas.scm.eastus2-01.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace/09363ba12457-e199d32e-04ce-4375-8fa5-2b14bce9f4e6.txt)
2024-09-13T13:30:26  Startup Request, url: /api/deployments/?api-version=2022-03-01, method: GET, type: request, pid: 87,1,22, ScmType: GitHubAction/home/LogFiles/kudu/trace/0d49f2e78976-8d18268c-ac7f-48b5-ba76-a2edd5a5b846.txt  (https://mosaic-strapi-c3e3g3ebavbmfyas.scm.eastus2-01.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace/0d49f2e78976-8d18268c-ac7f-48b5-ba76-a2edd5a5b846.txt)
2024-09-13T04:11:45  Startup Request, url: /api/deployments/?api-version=2022-03-01, method: GET, type: request, pid: 92,1,15, ScmType: None/home/LogFiles/kudu/trace/11aaaf1752dc-28760d7e-d2bf-46f2-9d36-ed7c5ced2ae7.txt  (https://mosaic-strapi-c3e3g3ebavbmfyas.scm.eastus2-01.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace/11aaaf1752dc-28760d7e-d2bf-46f2-9d36-ed7c5ced2ae7.txt)
2024-09-13T18:56:36  Startup Request, url: /webssh/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=P7ileVT&sid=VizFuZ9Dnr8qTSBbAAAI, method: POST, type: request, pid: 86,1,7, ScmType: GitHubAction/home/LogFiles/kudu/trace/43cbc01b1a2f-400f1e2d-7671-4206-8541-5cad6e5f5e7d.txt  (https://mosaic-strapi-c3e3g3ebavbmfyas.scm.eastus2-01.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace/43cbc01b1a2f-400f1e2d-7671-4206-8541-5cad6e5f5e7d.txt)
2024-09-13T14:30:30  Startup Request, url: /api/logstream/, method: GET, type: request, pid: 86,1,3, ScmType: GitHubAction/home/LogFiles/kudu/trace/467421bba544-fecbc1a7-2dd7-469e-ae22-dcafc1432808.txt  (https://mosaic-strapi-c3e3g3ebavbmfyas.scm.eastus2-01.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace/467421bba544-fecbc1a7-2dd7-469e-ae22-dcafc1432808.txt)
2024-09-13T20:11:51  Startup Request, url: /webssh/host, method: GET, type: request, pid: 86,1,5, ScmType: GitHubAction/home/LogFiles/kudu/trace/63e169a70a4f-4a2df148-305a-4928-afc5-081d37d327e1.txt  (https://mosaic-strapi-c3e3g3ebavbmfyas.scm.eastus2-01.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace/63e169a70a4f-4a2df148-305a-4928-afc5-081d37d327e1.txt)
2024-09-13T19:31:05  Startup Request, url: /api/publish?async=true&deployer=GITHUB_ONE_DEPLOY&type=zip&message=%7B%22type%22%3A%22deployment%22%2C%22sha%22%3A%22a2577ef3a326c864a83f9151ed84a7f51f0f30be%22%2C%22repoName%22%3A%22qiuzman%2Fmosaic-strapi%22%2C%22actor%22%3A%22qiuzman%22%2C%22slotName%22%3A%22Production%22%2C%22commitMessage%22%3A%22test%22%7D, method: POST, type: request, pid: 87,1,7, ScmType: GitHubAction/home/LogFiles/kudu/trace/726c87aaf59f-5d3d1f38-f3de-4c1d-bcca-e92656de62f6.txt  (https://mosaic-strapi-c3e3g3ebavbmfyas.scm.eastus2-01.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace/726c87aaf59f-5d3d1f38-f3de-4c1d-bcca-e92656de62f6.txt)
2024-09-13T14:13:37  Startup Request, url: /api/deployments/?$orderby=ReceivedTime%20desc&$top=20&api-version=2022-03-01, method: GET, type: request, pid: 92,1,37, ScmType: GitHubAction/home/LogFiles/kudu/trace/8d20faa3b872-54dfc596-a712-4c80-b82d-f14d55012e15.txt  (https://mosaic-strapi-c3e3g3ebavbmfyas.scm.eastus2-01.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace/8d20faa3b872-54dfc596-a712-4c80-b82d-f14d55012e15.txt)
2024-09-13T04:12:46  Startup Request, url: /api/deployments/?api-version=2022-03-01, method: GET, type: request, pid: 87,1,5, ScmType: GitHubAction/home/LogFiles/kudu/trace/9581b701eb8d-c5a6c0b1-d6d5-4051-ade3-8db39b8bf29c.txt  (https://mosaic-strapi-c3e3g3ebavbmfyas.scm.eastus2-01.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace/9581b701eb8d-c5a6c0b1-d6d5-4051-ade3-8db39b8bf29c.txt)
2024-09-13T16:44:58  Startup Request, url: /api/settings, method: GET, type: request, pid: 87,1,20, ScmType: GitHubAction/home/LogFiles/kudu/trace/9a560d65d95e-8b9aee07-7d61-4349-9b9b-5137e9759331.txt  (https://mosaic-strapi-c3e3g3ebavbmfyas.scm.eastus2-01.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace/9a560d65d95e-8b9aee07-7d61-4349-9b9b-5137e9759331.txt)
2024-09-13T20:02:08  Startup Request, url: /webssh/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=P7i-Y_P&sid=tFR3f3edb_1CJ0x9AAAA, method: POST, type: request, pid: 87,1,7, ScmType: GitHubAction/home/LogFiles/kudu/trace/9ae0e1bca9fd-f63c8aa6-e8cc-4767-8936-4733024d9d2a.txt  (https://mosaic-strapi-c3e3g3ebavbmfyas.scm.eastus2-01.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace/9ae0e1bca9fd-f63c8aa6-e8cc-4767-8936-4733024d9d2a.txt)
2024-09-13T19:08:37  Startup Request, url: /api/zipdeploy?author=ms-azuretools-vscode&deployer=ms-azuretools-vscode&isAsync=true&trackDeploymentId=true, method: POST, type: request, pid: 87,1,21, ScmType: GitHubAction/home/LogFiles/kudu/trace/9c8e653fbc3e-e501d448-9d57-46a1-90ec-c013f7fe4e6d.txt  (https://mosaic-strapi-c3e3g3ebavbmfyas.scm.eastus2-01.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace/9c8e653fbc3e-e501d448-9d57-46a1-90ec-c013f7fe4e6d.txt)
2024-09-13T14:57:55    Error occurred, type: error, text: LogStreamManager: ProcessRequest end
2024-09-13T14:57:55  Error occurred, type: error, text: LogStreamManager: Inside Reset/home/LogFiles/kudu/trace/9c8e653fbc3e-eee4bf94-8b5c-4f5f-99f5-335a9ac43ee4.txt  (https://mosaic-strapi-c3e3g3ebavbmfyas.scm.eastus2-01.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace/9c8e653fbc3e-eee4bf94-8b5c-4f5f-99f5-335a9ac43ee4.txt)
2024-09-13T14:36:40  Startup Request, url: /api/vfs/LogFiles/, method: GET, type: request, pid: 87,1,5, ScmType: GitHubAction/home/LogFiles/kudu/trace/9e2c20993d25-495cc99c-e91c-42b0-a941-76570e2cfb61.txt  (https://mosaic-strapi-c3e3g3ebavbmfyas.scm.eastus2-01.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace/9e2c20993d25-495cc99c-e91c-42b0-a941-76570e2cfb61.txt)
2024-09-13T13:20:51  Startup Request, url: /api/deployments/?$orderby=ReceivedTime%20desc&$top=20&api-version=2022-03-01, method: GET, type: request, pid: 87,1,3, ScmType: GitHubAction/home/LogFiles/kudu/trace/b340ef281130-ff05998d-0447-41be-9f71-121b5e88c50b.txt  (https://mosaic-strapi-c3e3g3ebavbmfyas.scm.eastus2-01.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace/b340ef281130-ff05998d-0447-41be-9f71-121b5e88c50b.txt)
2024-09-13T17:06:52  Startup Request, url: /api/deployments/temp-7826a9d8, method: GET, type: request, pid: 87,1,5, ScmType: GitHubAction/home/LogFiles/kudu/trace/e75b9e8c61d6-ce31b35a-9486-4efb-847c-7863561b2e6d.txt  (https://mosaic-strapi-c3e3g3ebavbmfyas.scm.eastus2-01.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace/e75b9e8c61d6-ce31b35a-9486-4efb-847c-7863561b2e6d.txt)
2024-09-13T03:50:53  Startup Request, url: /api/deployments/?$orderby=ReceivedTime%20desc&$top=20&api-version=2022-03-01, method: GET, type: request, pid: 85,1,5, ScmType: None/home/LogFiles/kudu/trace/e91c355f74f8-66ba0e0f-da3b-493c-9480-79360aa993b0.txt  (https://mosaic-strapi-c3e3g3ebavbmfyas.scm.eastus2-01.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace/e91c355f74f8-66ba0e0f-da3b-493c-9480-79360aa993b0.txt)
2024-09-13T16:36:23  Startup Request, url: /api/deployments/?$orderby=ReceivedTime%20desc&$top=20&api-version=2022-03-01, method: GET, type: request, pid: 86,1,5, ScmType: GitHubAction/home/LogFiles/kudu/trace/fe9116225d2e-4adb8484-a913-4737-b94e-042e22c614c8.txt  (https://mosaic-strapi-c3e3g3ebavbmfyas.scm.eastus2-01.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace/fe9116225d2e-4adb8484-a913-4737-b94e-042e22c614c8.txt)
2024-09-13T20:59:37  Startup Request, url: /webssh/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=P7jBoW5&sid=GgwzSZM4OtP47MRUAAAA, method: POST, type: request, pid: 87,1,7, ScmType: None/home/LogFiles/2024_09_13_lw1sdlwk000109_default_docker.log  (https://mosaic-strapi-c3e3g3ebavbmfyas.scm.eastus2-01.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/2024_09_13_lw1sdlwk000109_default_docker.log)
2024-09-13T21:39:47.492571021Z 2024-09-13T21:39:47: PM2 log: [PM2] Serving /home/site/wwwroot/dist/build on port 8080
2024-09-13T21:39:47.747286316Z 2024-09-13T21:39:47: PM2 log: ????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
2024-09-13T21:39:47.747333116Z ??? id ??? name                       ??? namespace   ??? version ??? mode    ??? pid      ??? uptime ??? ???    ??? status    ??? cpu      ??? mem      ??? user     ??? watching ???
2024-09-13T21:39:47.747349516Z ????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
2024-09-13T21:39:47.747356216Z ??? 0  ??? static-page-server-8080    ??? default     ??? 5.3.1   ??? fork    ??? 102      ??? 0s     ??? 0    ??? online    ??? 0%       ??? 37.5mb   ??? root     ??? disabled ???
2024-09-13T21:39:47.747360716Z ????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
2024-09-13T21:39:47.793315662Z 2024-09-13T21:39:47: PM2 log: [--no-daemon] Continue to stream logs
2024-09-13T21:39:47.793349763Z 2024-09-13T21:39:47: PM2 log: [--no-daemon] Exit on target PM2 exit pid=89
2024-09-13T21:39:49.574706853Z 21:39:49 0|static-page-server-8080  | Exposing /home/site/wwwroot/dist/build directory on 0.0.0.0:8080/home/LogFiles/2024_09_13_lw1sdlwk000109_docker.log  (https://mosaic-strapi-c3e3g3ebavbmfyas.scm.eastus2-01.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/2024_09_13_lw1sdlwk000109_docker.log)
2024-09-13T20:59:38.853Z INFO  - Recycling container because of AppSettingsChange and isMainSite = True
2024-09-13T20:59:41.444Z INFO  - Starting container for site
2024-09-13T20:59:41.445Z INFO  - docker run -d --expose=8080 --name mosaic-strapi_7_2f428551 -e WEBSITE_USE_DIAGNOSTIC_SERVER=true -e PORT=8080 -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=mosaic-strapi -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=mosaic-strapi-c3e3g3ebavbmfyas.eastus2-01.azurewebsites.net -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=9e332d9ad782a006d1770f3ea21a0947300e24c48bdf697e9d4afffcd4ca080a -e HTTP_LOGGING_ENABLED=1 appsvc/node:20-lts_20240819.2.tuxprod pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot/dist/build --no-daemon --spa
2024-09-13T21:00:10.173Z INFO  - Initiating warmup request to container mosaic-strapi_7_2f428551 for site mosaic-strapi
2024-09-13T21:00:44.484Z INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container mosaic-strapi_7_2f428551. Elapsed time = 34.3108961 sec
2024-09-13T21:00:54.393Z INFO  - Container mosaic-strapi_7_2f428551 for site mosaic-strapi initialized successfully and is ready to serve requests.
2024-09-13T21:39:24.007Z INFO  - Starting container for site
2024-09-13T21:39:24.010Z INFO  - docker run -d --expose=8080 --name mosaic-strapi_8_2e967d3f -e WEBSITE_USE_DIAGNOSTIC_SERVER=true -e PORT=8080 -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=mosaic-strapi -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=mosaic-strapi-c3e3g3ebavbmfyas.eastus2-01.azurewebsites.net -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=9e332d9ad782a006d1770f3ea21a0947300e24c48bdf697e9d4afffcd4ca080a -e HTTP_LOGGING_ENABLED=1 appsvc/node:20-lts_20240819.2.tuxprod pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot/dist/build --no-daemon --spa
2024-09-13T21:39:30.007Z INFO  - Initiating warmup request to container mosaic-strapi_8_2e967d3f for site mosaic-strapi
2024-09-13T21:39:50.142Z INFO  - Container mosaic-strapi_8_2e967d3f for site mosaic-strapi initialized successfully and is ready to serve requests.Ending Log Tail of existing logs ---Starting Live Log Stream ---
2024-09-13T21:56:41  No new trace in the past 1 min(s).

Console in the browser on that page shows the following error:
strapi-DTVbBIX9.js:2615 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isEE')
at _0e (strapi-DTVbBIX9.js:2615:11967)


If possible, share your GitHub repo without any secrets?
